# Composite Api Objects and Referencing RecordTypes

Tags: api, rest, record-type

Is there anyway to reference an account recordtype by Name when creating an account using **Composite API** which has recordtypes? I am hoping there is a way so I don't need to do a get request to get a RecordTypeId and associate it with my accounts.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you simply build a reference object, like this:

```
"RecordType": { "attributes": { "sobjectType": "RecordType" }, "Name": "Household" }
```

Of course, this will fail if the user doesn't have access to the record type, or if more or less than one record type has this exact name for this object.

This works anywhere that you could put a RecordTypeId attribute, including insert/update commands, composite commands, sobject tree commands, etc.

---

If you're getting duplicate record errors, you can run a query to get the record you need first. Here's an example composite request that does this:

```
{
    "allOrNone": true,
    "compositeRequest": [
        {
            "url": "/services/data/v44.0/query?q=select+Id+from+recordtype+where+sobjecttype=%27account%27+and+name=%27household%27",
            "method": "GET",
            "referenceId": "recType"
        },
        {
            "url": "/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Account",
            "method": "POST",
            "referenceId": "householdAccount",
            "body": {
                "Name": "John Doe Family",
                "RecordTypeId": "@{recType.records[0].Id}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hello sfdcfox.  I do have the same recordtype name "General" which is used on account and another recordtype "General" used on contact.  So from what I understand this will always Error?  I was referencing the sobject type "RecordType": { "attributes": { "sobjectType": "Account" }, "Name": "General" } but I am getting a Duplicate Failure

Comment: @DerrickE yes, you can get duplicate errors in this case. I added an example of how to query the record type without having to make round trips to the server. This may help you without needing to rename a record type.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yah I wanted to avoid using a get request because each upsert can be different record types and  trying to just upsert them regardless of what recordtype.   I may just change the recordtype name.