# Referencing RecordType by name in Tree Request

Tags: rest-api, record-type, sobject-tree

Is there a way to reference a record type by name in tree requests?

My example payload:

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "LastName": "Doe",
            "RecordType": { 
                "attributes": { 
                    "sobjectType": "RecordType" 
                 }, 
                 "Name": "Employee" 
            }
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Account",
                "referenceId": "ref1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, the API responses with an error:

```
{
    "hasErrors": true,
    "results": [
        {
            "referenceId": "ref1",
            "errors": [
                {
                    "statusCode": "INVALID_FIELD",
                    "message": "Cannot reference a foreign key field RecordType.",
                    "fields": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note:** This question is closely related to [Composite Api Objects and Referencing RecordTypes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239239/composite-api-objects-and-referencing-recordtypes). Although stated in the accepted answer, the solution obviously does not work for tree requests, but for composite requests only.